# When I call DisplayAlert in a Xamarin app, the screen fades but no alert is displayed

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I'm completely new to Xamarin so this is probably something really obvious. But when I run my Xamarin app that has a DisplayAlert call, the screen fades but no dialog appears:

```
<Button x:Name="PlayButton" Text="Play" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="200" FontSize="64" Clicked="PlayButton_ClickedAsync"/>
```

```
private async void PlayButton_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Play", "This is where we would start the game.", "OK");
}
```

How do I make this alert actually display? I'm testing with a UWP app, if it matters, until the Android emulator finishes downloading...

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9756

Comment: Wow... This serious bug has been known for almost four months now and it has not been fixed?!

Comment: Is there a way to temporarily downgrade my Xamarin to an old, working version?

Comment: XF is just a nuget package, you can select any version you like in the Nuget manager

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** , this issue also exists in the current version of Xamarin Forms (`4.6`).

You can downgrade XF to the `4.4` version to make it work as a workaround now .

Downgrade follow this steps :

1. Right click project **solution**
2. selcet **Manage Nuget Packages For Solution...**

[image]

3. Find installed xamarin forms nuget packages ,and select the wanted version to install

[image]